# Can i make htmlunit scraper work on multi pages?

Tags: web-scraping, htmlunit

I have a question about htmlunit scraper.I know that Scraper get information by name of html elements.Can i make htmlunit scraper work on multi pages?

Comment: htmlunit is a library, you can just write some code to deal with multiple pages (or am I missing something?)

Comment: I mean If I have 20 pages in different websites,can I make one program to scrape them? or must make scraper for each page?

Comment: if they're X% the same thing, you probably can write code that will reuse X%